# Security Domain with multiple login modules just works for Database login

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

So I tested picketlink example for facebook, and I copied all the files to my current app and they work.

My app allows users to register and use the site under my websites account and the idea is to add facebook and openid support too.

So everything seems to work except for when I try to enter a folder under  my security domain.

```
http://localhost:8080/mapache/pages/secure
```

If I try to access anything there I see my login.jsp page with the field for user and password and I can log with the users from my database,

But the problem is with my facebook authentication

this is my security domain on my standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="mapacheSecurity">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.picketlink.social.facebook.FacebookLoginModule" flag="sufficient"/>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="sufficient">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/mapacheDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from usuario where lower(usuario)=lower(?) and activo = 'true'"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select 1, 'Roles' from usuario where ? is not null"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

But when I access to my fb.jsf, the page that is basically a copy of home.xhtml from the picketlink facebook example, it seems to log correctly, it ask for my facebook user and password and it redirects back to my fb.jsf page and I get the message that I am logged and I and log out button, but if I try to access anything under my secure **folder** I need to use a user and password from my database.

Is this line correct, what else do I need:

```
 <login-module code="org.picketlink.social.facebook.FacebookLoginModule" flag="sufficient"/>
```